# .NET 4.0 Table Adapter connection string issue

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net

I have a weird issue occuring when using table adaper connection strings in a .net 4.0 web application.
I'm using the same connection string name with different server/credentials for the test 
and production environments.  I comment out the connection string that I'm not using(see example 
below) I'm having an issue with the table adapter not using the current connection string that is uncommented in the web config file.  For example, I make any changes against the test database using the test connection string.  However, when I uncomment the production connection string(and comment the test connection string) and deploy to the production server, the test connection is still being used.  Some of the connections are not defined in the code behind - some are grids that are bound to objectdatasources.  Can anyone offer any advice on to fix this problem?

```
<!-- Test Conn  -->
  <add name="Connection1" connectionString="Data Source=server1; Initial Catalog=database1; User ID=username1; Password=password1" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>

<!-- Production
  <add name="Connection1" connectionString="Data Source=server2; Initial Catalog=database1;User ID=username2; Password=password2" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
-->
```

Comment: that long space in the first connectionString between User and ID makes me itchy. make sure you change the Web.config file within the top directory and not in a subdirectory. make sure you restart the web server.

Comment: Are you restarting the web server?

Comment: If you're developing locally, have you tried a clean and rebuild? I used to see this in ASP.NET 2.0 sites when my temporary internet files would get stuck. I had to stop IIS on my local machine, dig into the .NET temporary internet files, and delete everything. (It's not a problem on every machine, but on machines where it happens it's a pain)

Comment: Are you asking if I restart the production web server? If so, then the answer is no.  There are many web applications on the production web server and I don't want to cause more issues.  I'm developing locally and I have tried a clean and rebuild.  When I deploy, I'm not sure which connection string will be using in production.  When the wrong connection string is being i used, I perform another clean, rebuild, and deploy until it finally uses the correct connection.  I'm just not sure why this is happening.

Comment: IIS has to read the Web.Config.  Apparently your "deploy" is not always forcing it to read the Web.Config.

Answer (score 0):

Try restarting IIS after you deploy.